# how to decrypt a file in python which was encrypted using openssl

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

I encrypted a file using `openssl` using the below command

```
cat input.txt
hello world
openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:'00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff' -iv a2a8a78be66075c94ca5be53c8865251 -nosalt -base64 -in input.txt -out output.txt
cat output.txt
pt7DqtAwtTjPbTlzVApucQ==
```

How can i decrypt the file using python Crypto package. I tried the below and it didn't work.

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> from base64 import b64decode
>>> with open('output.txt') as f:
...     aes = AES.new('00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff', AES.MODE_CBC, IV='a2a8a78be66075c94ca5be53c8865251'.decode('hex'))
...     print(aes.decrypt(b64decode(f.read())))
...
L�|�L   ��O�*$&9�
```

I need a way to encrypt a file using openssl aes-256-cbc cipher and decrypt in python

Comment: use the -P option to openssl to print out the key and IV, then supply those to your python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password is not the key. Openssl uses [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) to create an appropriate key (& IV, if necessary) from the password and the salt.

As James K Polk mentions in a comment, you can use the -P (or -p) option to tell Openssl to print the key (in hex ), which you can then pass to Crypto.Cipher. Alternatively, you can implement `EVP_BytesToKey` in Python, as shown below. This is a simplified version of `EVP_BytesToKey` that uses no salt, and the default value of 1 for the `count` arg.

As the `EVP_BytesToKey` docs state, this is a rather weak password derivation function. As the [hashlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation) mention, modern password derivation normally performs hundreds of thousands of hashes to make password hashing attacks very slow.

We also need a function to remove the [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) from the decrypted data bytes. The `unpad` function below simply assumes that the padding data is valid. In real software the `unpad` function must verify that the padded data is valid to prevent padding-based attacks. My `unpad` function also assumes the data has been encoded as UTF-8 bytes and decodes the unpadded data to text.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode
from hashlib import md5

def evp_simple(data):
    out = ''
    while len(out) < 32:
        out += md5(out + data).digest()
    return out[:32]

def unpad(s):
    offset = ord(s[-1])
    return s[:-offset].decode('utf-8')

iv = 'a2a8a78be66075c94ca5be53c8865251'.decode('hex')
passwd = '00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff'
key = evp_simple(passwd)
print('key', key.encode('hex'))

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

data = b64decode('pt7DqtAwtTjPbTlzVApucQ==')

raw = aes.decrypt(data)
print(repr(raw), len(raw))
plain = unpad(raw)
print(repr(plain), len(plain))
```

**output**

```
key b4377f7babf2991b7d6983c4d3e19cd4dd37e31af1c9c689ca22e90e365be18b
'hello world\n\x04\x04\x04\x04' 16
u'hello world\n' 12
```

---

That code will not run on Python 3, so here's a Python 3 version.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode
from hashlib import md5

def evp_simple(data):
    out = b''
    while len(out) < 32:
        out += md5(out + data).digest()
    return out[:32]

def unpad(s):
    offset = s[-1]
    return s[:-offset].decode('utf-8')

iv = bytes.fromhex('a2a8a78be66075c94ca5be53c8865251')
passwd = b'00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff'
key = evp_simple(passwd)

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

data = b64decode('pt7DqtAwtTjPbTlzVApucQ==')

raw = aes.decrypt(data)
print(repr(raw), len(raw))
plain = unpad(raw)
print(repr(plain), len(plain))
```

**output**

```
b'hello world\n\x04\x04\x04\x04' 16
'hello world\n' 12
```